# Why does strptime() append a time value even when not specified?

Tags: datetime, python-3.7, strptime

I have the following Python code:

```
print ('2020-02-09')
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-09'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

which yields

```
2020-02-09
2020-02-09 00:00:00
```

Is there a better choice of functions which does not return the number of seconds?  IOW, how can I compare the two values without having the time component evaluated?  E.G.:

```
if datetime.datetime.today().date() == datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-09'], '%Y-%m-%d'):
```

For clarification, my goal is to store the date (no time value) as an attribute in a JSON file and then during runtime compare it to datetime.now().date() or datetime.today().date().

Comment: The code in your question has a parse error.  Can you please post the actual code you are executing?

Comment: @NateEldredge  that is the actual code with the exception that the '2020-02-09' is a JSON attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

if dt.today().date() == dt.strptime('2020-02-09', '%Y-%m-%d').date():
```

Note the inclusion of the `.date()` trailing the second operand.

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare the date part of both the function:
just add date() at the end of

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-02-09', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this too much and also missing the ability to chain .date() to the function.  Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Here is what I decided to go with:

```
#example date for JSON attribute
data['lastWritten'] = '2020-02-09'
if str(datetime.datetime.today().date()) == data['lastWritten']:
```